# How to create rabbitmq non-durable queues

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-websocket

When using Spring Websockets with Stomp and full broker, how to create non-durable queues for each session in rabbitmq.

Queues should be deleted once the session is over.

Comment: I found that since RMQ 3.6 you can use subscription headers to make a queue non-durable (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stomp/issues/24). But besides that I haven't seen much. Seems like I'll likely be writing my own queue cleanup logic :(